# camel test replace seda with direct in original route

Tags: apache-camel, camel-test

camel test, replace seda with direct.

In my camel route test i wants to replace seda call with direct for example

instead of "seda:Second_route_id" my consumer should be "direct:Second_route_id" for test

### Following is my original route

```
from("direct:First_route_id").id("First_route_id")
.process() // bla bla
.multicast()
.to("Second_route_id");

---
from("seda:Second_route_id").id("Second_route_id")
.proces() // save data
.end()
```

i tried to do some thing like

```
    context.getRouteDefination("First_route_id").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithoutRouteBuilder(){
    public void configure(){
// but it gave me error no consumer found for "direct: Second_route_id"
    weaveById("Second_route_id").before().to("direct: Second_route_id "); 
    }
    })
```

Comment: There is a replaceFromWith you can use to change seda to direct etc.

Comment: i appreciate brining my attention to this method. works for me. if you copy paste in answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `replaceFromWith` method you can use to change seda to direct when using advice with.

Answer (score 0):

`replaceFromWith` is one possible way:

```
    camelContext.getRouteDefinition("Second_route_id").adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            replaceFromWith("direct:Second_route_id");
        }
    });
```